# Schedule emails to send using mailgun 40 minutes after a user submits form

Tags: laravel, email, scheduled-tasks, mailgun

I am trying to schedule an email to be sent on some event (Sign Up). In detail, if a person signs up, I want to send the email to the user after 1 hour has passed.

I am using **Laravel** and **Mailgun** for sending emails.

```
Mail::send('emails.signup_notification', $messageData, function($message) use ($messageData)
    {
        $message->to('xyz@gmail.com')
            ->from('abc@gmail.com', 'Admin')
            ->subject("Notification Signup (#" . $messageData['id'] . ")");
    });
```

How can I schedule this sending email to send email after 1 hour?

I have been searching for information around this and found the following Documentation from mailgun

**Documentation**
[Tips & Tricks: Scheduling Email Delivery](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/tips-tricks-scheduling-email-delivery)

How can I use it in my code to schedule the email?

Comment: I think you have to schedule a command for do this

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta what sort of a command you are taking about

Comment: i an talking about cron jobs

Comment: i think is not i am after i want mailgun to schedule the emails

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel and you need to implement a queue to handle your emails.

Once you have the emails configured with a queue, you can use the `->later()` configuration to set a delay timer.

See the following link for more information.

[Laravel Mail Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#queueing-mail)

### Example:

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->later($when, new OrderShipped($order));
```

Comment: well, I have gone through the documents, and it's perfectly fine, and I implemented this late function

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I have implemented the logic using mailable classes, and use the late function it's sending email instantly.

Comment: i am just stuck at the end my jobs are processed but I didn't receive the email

Comment: Can you check mailgun to see if it arrived as expected?

Comment: the email is on delay and work perfectly fine, can you please tell me how to setup when throwing it into production, and how to automate  queues that it listen for all the time